# Accesing variable name passed as argument inside apply

Tags: r

I made almost the same question in another post, but asking just for column name, and received a perfect solution for that need. Now what I need is the **variable full name**. I reformulate here.

I use 'deparse(substitute(x))' from inside my function to get variable name passed as parameter. It works great... but not with 'lapply'

```
myfun <- function(x)
{
  return(deparse(substitute(x)))
}

a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,5)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
myfun(df$a)

[1] "df$a"
```

but, with 'lapply'...

```
lapply(df, myfun)
$a
[1] "X[[i]]"

$b
[1] "X[[i]]"
```

How can I get the variable name inside 'lapply'?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a data frame to `lapply`, it iterates through the columns by *numerical* indexing using the double square bracket, not *name* indexing using the `$` accessor. It is equivalent to using the following loop:

```r
X <- df
result <- list()

for(i in seq_along(X)) {
  result[[i]] <- myfun(X[[i]])
} 

names(result) <- names(X)

result
#> $a
#> [1] "X[[i]]"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "X[[i]]"
```

So a simple `deparse(substitute(x))` will not work inside `lapply`. You are not *recovering* the column name, but rather would need to *reconstruct* it from the call stack. This is full of caveats and gotchas, but a (relatively) simple approach would be:

```r
myfun <- function(x) {
  stack <- lapply(sys.calls(), function(x) sapply(as.list(x), deparse))
  
  if(stack[[length(stack)]][1] == 'myfun') {
    return(stack[[length(stack)]][2])
  }
  
  if(stack[[length(stack)]][1] == 'FUN') {
    return(paste0(stack[[length(stack) - 1]][2], '$',
           eval(quote(names(X)[i]), parent.frame())))
  }
  
  deparse(substitute(x))
}
```

This means your function will still work if called directly:

```
myfun(df$a)
#> [1] "df$a"
```

But will also work within `lapply`

```
lapply(df, myfun)
#> $a
#> [1] "df$a"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "df$b"

lapply(iris, myfun)
#> $Sepal.Length
#> [1] "iris$Sepal.Length"
#>
#> $Sepal.Width
#> [1] "iris$Sepal.Width"
#>
#> $Petal.Length
#> [1] "iris$Petal.Length"
#>
#> $Petal.Width
#> [1] "iris$Petal.Width"
#>
#> $Species
#> [1] "iris$Species"
```

It is specifically written to cover direct use or use within `lapply`. If you wanted to expand its use to work within other functional calls like `Map` or the various `purrr` mapping functions, then these would have to be covered specifically by their own `if` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

We can define a character string '**col_name**'to take the name of the data frame column in the function. For example, if col_name is "a", df[[col_name]] extracts "a" column from data frame.Then we can use the paste() function to concatenate the string 'df$' and 'col_name':

```
   myfun <- function(col_name) {
  col <- df[[col_name]]
  return(paste("df$", col_name, sep = ""))
}


 lapply(colnames(df), myfun)
```

output

```
[[1]]
[1] "df$a"

[[2]]
[1] "df$b"
```

If we would like to assign any data we could do the assignment and then run lapply for example:

```
df <- iris
lapply(colnames(df), myfun)
```

output

```
[[1]]
[1] "df$Sepal.Length"

[[2]]
[1] "df$Sepal.Width"

[[3]]
[1] "df$Petal.Length"

[[4]]
[1] "df$Petal.Width"

[[5]]
[1] "df$Species"
```

I hope this could helps.

Comment: But now this won't work if the data frame is called anything other than `df`, and it won't work if called directly (for example `myfun(df$a)` no longer gives the expected output.

Comment: Allan, you are right! before applying lapply(), we could the assign the data to df. For example: df<-iris. Thats what I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, its a bit verbose and Allen's solution is much better:

```r
myfun <- function(x) {
  pf <- parent.frame()
  x_nm <- deparse(substitute(x))
  frame_n <- sys.nframe()
  
  apply <- FALSE
  while(frame_n > 0) {
    cl <- as.list(sys.call(frame_n))
    if (grepl("apply", cl[[1]])) {
      x_obj <- cl[[2]]
      apply <- TRUE
      break
    }
    frame_n <- frame_n - 1L
  }
  
  if (apply) {
    idx <- parent.frame()$i[]  
    obj <- get(x_obj, envir = pf)
    if (!is.null(names(obj)[idx])) {
      nm_or_idx <- names(obj)[idx]
    } else {
      nm_or_idx <- idx
    }
    x_nm <- paste0(x_obj, '$', nm_or_idx)
  }
  
  return(x_nm)
}


myfun(df$a)
#> [1] "df$a"

lapply(df, myfun)
#> $a
#> [1] "df$a"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "df$b"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: NIce, +1. I do think that getting info from the call stack like this is the only option.